# Pickle tf.Gradient.Tape() throws Error: TypeError: can't pickle tfe.Tape objects

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pickle, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I try to perform split-learning, which means the model is devided and trained on a client up to a specific layer. The output, labels and trainablevariables and GradientTape of the clientside model are sent to a server to complete the training on the second half of the model. On the server, a serverside gradient is calculated to update the server and a clientside gradient is calculated. The clientside gradient should be sent back to the client to update the clientside model.

The problem is that i cannot pickle a tf.GradintTape(), which is necessary to transmit to the server in order to compute the clientside gradients. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle tfe.Tape objects
```

You can see the server and client code below

client:

```
import os
import struct
import socket
from threading import Thread
import pickle 
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout



host = '192.168.178.190'
port = 10080
max_recv = 4096


def send_msg(sock, getid, content):
    msg = [getid, content]  # add getid
    msg = pickle.dumps(msg)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg  # add 4-byte length in network byte order
    sock.sendall(msg)


def recieve_msg(sock):
    msg = recv_msg(sock)  
    msg = pickle.loads(msg)
    getid = msg[0]
    content = msg[1]
    #handle_request(sock, getid, content)
    return content

def recv_msg(sock):
    # read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)


def recvall(sock, n):

    data = b''
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data += packet
    return data



fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

#pixel der bilder von 0-255 auf 0-1 herunterscalen
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0


#client klasse
class Client(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train):
        super(Client, self).__init__()


        self.num_samples = x_train.shape[0] 
        self.train_inputs = tf.expand_dims(x_train, 3) 
        self.train_labels = y_train #Traingslabel für erzeugten clienten
        # Hyperparameters
        self.batch_size = 50
        self.epochs = 2

        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([Conv2D(32, (3,3), (1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'),
                                         MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
                                         Dropout(0.25),
                                         Conv2D(64, (3,3), (1,1), activation='relu')])

        # Optimizer
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2)

    #get the output of clientside model with given inputs
    def call(self, inputs):
        output = self.model(inputs)
        return output

    def send(self, i):
        start, end = i * self.batch_size, (i + 1) * self.batch_size 
        output_client = self.call(self.train_inputs[start:end]) 

        labels = self.train_labels[start:end] 
        return output_client, labels




    def start_train(self, sock,  batchround):
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            print("Starte Trainingsepoche: ", i + 1)
            for batchround in range(
                    self.num_samples // self.batch_size):  
                with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                    output_client, labels = self.send(batchround)  

                    inputclient = tf.expand_dims(x_test, 3)

                    test_output_client, test_labels = self.call(inputclient), y_test
                    client_trainable_variables = self.model.trainable_variables
                    msg = {
                        'client_out': output_client,
                        'label': labels,
                        'client_output_test': test_output_client,
                        'client_label_test': test_labels,
                        'gradient_tape': tape,
                        'trainable_variables': client_trainable_variables,
                        }
                    print(tape)
                    send_msg(sock, 0, msg)
                    backmsg = recieve_msg(sock)
                    l = backmsg["loss"]
                    gradient_client = tape.gradient(l, client_trainable_variables)
                    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_client, self.model.trainable_variables))
                    print(backmsg['test_status'], "samples:", batchround*self.batch_size, "von", self.num_samples)



def main():
    global client
    client = Client(x_train, y_train)
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    client.start_train(s, 0)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

server:

```
import os
import struct
import socket
from threading import Thread
import pickle
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout

host = '0.0.0.0'#'localhost'
port = 10080
max_recv = 4096
max_numclients = 5
connectedclients = []
trds = []

def send_msg(sock, content):
    msg = pickle.dumps(content)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg #add 4-byte length in netwwork byte order
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recieve_msg(sock):
    msg = recv_msg(sock)  
    msg = pickle.loads(msg)
    getid = msg[0]
    content = msg[1]
    handle_request(sock, getid, content)


def recv_msg(sock):

    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]   
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock, n):

    data = b''
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data += packet
    return data

def handle_request(sock, getid, content):
        switcher = {
            0: server.calc_gradients,
            1: sendtoallcliets,
        }
        switcher.get(getid, "invalid request recieved")(sock, content)

def clientHandler(conn, addr):
     while True:
            try:
                recieve_msg(conn)
            except:
                pass


def sendtoallcliets(conn, content):
    ret="nachricht an alle clienten"

    for client in connectedclients:
        try:
            send_msg(client, ret)
        except:
            pass



class Server(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()


        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([Conv2D(128, (3,3), (1,1), activation='relu'),
                                          Dropout(0.4),
                                          Flatten(),
                                          Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                                          Dropout(0.4),
                                          Dense(10, activation='softmax')])


        self.loss_function = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1e-2)


    def call(self, input):
        output = self.model(input)
        return output


    def loss(self, output_server, labels):
        return self.loss_function(labels, output_server)

    def calc_gradients(self, sock, msg):
        tape_gradient = msg["gradient_tape"]
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            output_client, labels, trainable_variables_client = msg["client_out"], msg["label"], msg[
                "trainable_variables"]
            output_client_test, labels_test = msg['client_output_test'], msg['client_label_test']
            output_server = self.call(output_client)


            l = self.loss(output_server, labels)  
        gradient_server = tape.gradient(l,self.model.trainable_variables)  
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_server,self.model.trainable_variables))  
        gradient_client = tape_gradient.gradient(l, trainable_variables_client)
        predictions = np.argmax(self.call(output_client_test), axis=1)
        acc = np.mean(predictions == labels_test)
        test_status = "test_loss: {:.4f}, test_acc: {:.2f}%".format(l, acc * 100)
        print(test_status)

        backmsg = {
            'test_status': test_status,
            'gradient_client': gradient_client,
        }
        send_msg(sock, backmsg)



def main():
    global server
    server=Server()

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(max_numclients)

    for i in range(max_numclients):
        c, addr = s.accept()
        connectedclients.append(c)
        #print(connectedclients)
        print('Conntected with', addr)
        t = Thread(target=clientHandler, args=(c, addr))
        trds.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in trds:
        t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```